# Automorphism of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, maximal-and-prime-ideals, gaussian-elimination

Say we have $r$ linear polynomials $p_1,\ldots,p_r\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ which are linearly independent. How can we establish an automorphism of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ such that each $p_i$ goes to $x_i$? I know it has something to do with gaussian elimination, but I have no clue on how to proceed.

Comment: What if $p_i = a_ix_1$?

Comment: I meant to say linear independent polynomials, sorry.

Comment: Hint: Make the coefficients of $p_i$ into a matrix in $GL_n(k)$ and then construct an inverse homomorphism using the coefficients of the inverse of that matrix.

Comment: What about the zero degree terms?